Until, till present perfect
1 I won't go until it is working
2 I won't go until it has been working
1 is correct and means that once it works I may go. Is present perfect continuous okay here too. I feel that present perfect continuous emphasizes an action that started in the past and continues up to the present. "Until" typically refers to a specific point in time in the future when something will happen. That's why I don't think 2 is correct. Am I wrong and perfect continuous is okay with "until"?

(2) is not correct unless you add a time expression. I won't go until it has been working for at least ten minutes.

@KateBunting Do you think that a time expression is always obligatory to make present perfect continuous plus untill correct? For instance "It won't be wet untill it has been raining" is also wrong without a time expression?

I suppose that's OK, but there is no need for the continuous tense here. "Until it rains" or "until it has rained" would express the same idea.

@Gregor, I agree with Kate. 2. definitely has a time expression missing. You could possibly construct a scenario where a time expression had already been mentioned and was therefore implied, but even then you would be better with "I won't go until then".

@KateBunting  why my example with "working" needs a time expression but the other one with "raining" is fine without that?

@timchessish I'd like to give you the same question as i gave to Kate.

Why does my example with 'working' need a time expression? As I have told you many times, it isn't about 'grammatical rules', but about what it is natural for people to say. There is simply no need for the continuous tense unless you are talking about something having happened for a certain period of time. (I didn't say it was 'fine', just that I supposed that it could possibly be used.)

@KateBunting thank you very much

As Kate has said "I won't go until it has been working" on it's own just sounds wrong to a native speaker. Because you wouldn't normally use this without a time expression, if you do then you are expecting a time expression to follow which never comes.
